# DomParser JS changes attribute values

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome, browser

I have a weird problem and are looking for an alternative or solution to the following:

I have the following xml stored in a string:

```
'<revision id="2832276" title="`~!@#$%^&amp;amp;*()_-+={}|\\\\][:&amp;quot;;&amp;apos;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;,./_æåøÆÅØ_色" type="major" date="2022-05-25T13:53:28.650" comment="`~!@#$%^&amp;amp;*()_-+={}|\\\\][:&amp;quot;;&amp;apos;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;,./_æåøÆÅØ_"/>'
```

now if notice the values of title it changes I copy paste it into chrome or if i use the DOM parser:

```
.getElementsByTagName('revision')[0].getAttribute('title')
```

I get:

```
'`~!@#$%^&amp;*()_-+={}|\\\\][:&quot;;&apos;&lt;&gt;,./_æåøÆÅØ_色'
```

I have initialized the DOMParser like:

```
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(
                        xml,
                        'application/xml'
                    );
```

Comment: I cannot see the change you are talking about. can you please point it out

Comment: you should keep in mind that any attribute is HTML entities decoded when you get it

Answer (score 0):

Special characters have to be escaped in XML/HTML, for example `&` has to be escaped as `&amp;`, and the job of the parser is to give you the original unescaped value. So if the lexical XML contains `&amp;`, the parser will give you `&`, and if the lexical XML contains `&amp;amp;`, the parser will give you `&amp;`.

Comment: Hi Michael is there an alternative for looping through xml and extract the attributes raw content in JS. I have only found the dom parser so far... The only way I see is to use multple 4loops...

Comment: Why would you want to access XML without parsing it fully?